# Integrating ngrx/Store to an existing Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have an Angular 7 project that is currently and has lots of components that talk to an API and updates data from it.
The is constantly refreshed using setTimeout so it's getting very busy with all the components refreshing data from the API.

I am therefore thinking of adding ngrx/Store to the project.

Is ngrx/Store a solution for this kind of issue or should I look for other solutions?

Comment: I dont know rxjs/store, is ngrx/store what u looking for?. Anyway, if there is a constantly refresh of the data you should think about to talk to your api via websockets

Comment: I think you're talking about NgRx/Store. If that's the case, consider reading some articles on where to use NgRx and what can you benefit from. If your app is getting busy by requesting information each X time, NgRx will centralize it for you and provide a better way to your components to query info, but maybe won't fix your "a lot of request in parallel". Maybe what you really need is a websocket. Good thing is there's a good part of the community that thinks websocket is really good to work with NgRx.

Comment: I apologize...I rean't ngrx /store ..

Comment: Use ngrx/store if your components has complex interactions with each other. Data is modified in multiple places etc. Check [this](https://medium.com/default-to-open/understanding-a-large-scale-angular-app-with-ngrx-80f9fc5660cc) article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it's easy for you. I would say yes because ngrx provide API to break the application into smaller peice.

If you have multiple feature you will have 1 main store and for every feature you will have feature store connect to main store. So you can easy manage everything into feature seperation concern.

Another thing is ngrx provide effect middleware allow user to working with side effect like API call so you will have completely seprate code when working with API

I would recommend you read there small demo [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/example-app/src/app) for every feature they create `effects, actions, reducers, selector, services.`